# How to use XmlInclude to specify types dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml, object, xmlinclude

I have these classes which I use:

```
namespace defaultNamespace
{
    ...
    public class DataModel
    {
    }
    public class Report01
        {get; set;}
    public class Report02
        {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a method that creates the XML below.

```
public XmlDocument ObjectToXml(object response, string OutputPath)
{
    Type type = response.GetType();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(type);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, response);
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    stream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    xmldoc.Load(sReader);
    stream.Position = 0;
    string tmpPath = OutputPath;
    while (File.Exists(tmpPath))
    {
        File.Delete(tmpPath);
    }
    xmldoc.Save(tmpPath);
    return xmldoc;
}
```

And I have two lists that has a Report01 and Report02 object.

```
List<object> objs = new List<object>();
List<object> objs2 = new List<object>();

Report01 obj = new Report01();
obj.prop1 = "aa";
obj.prop2 = "bb";
objs.Add(obj);

Report02 obj2 = new Report02();
obj2.prop1 = "cc";
obj2.prop2 = "dd";
objs2.Add(obj2);
```

When I try to create the XML like this:

```
ObjectToXml(objs, "c:\\12\\objs.xml");
ObjectToXml(objs2, "c:\\12\\objs2.xml");
```

I see this exception:

> The type "Report01(or Report02)" was not expected. Use the XmlInclude
>   or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known
>   statically.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `response.GetType()` actually returns `List<object>` type and then you tried to serialize non expected type. `Object` don't know anything about your types and serializer for `Object` can't serialize your unknown types.

You can use BaseClass for your reports and `XmlInclude` to solve this exception:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Report01)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Report02)]
public class BaseClass { }
public class Report01 : BaseClass { ... }
public class Report02 : BaseClass { ... }

List<BaseClass> objs = new List<BaseClass>();
List<BaseClass> objs2 = new List<BaseClass>();
// fill collections here
ObjectToXml(objs, "c:\\12\\objs.xml");
ObjectToXml(objs2, "c:\\12\\objs2.xml");
```

Comment: So, you say that i need to create a base class that Report01 and Report02 will inherit. Right?

Comment: Yes, because you can't add `XmlIncludeAttribute` to the `Object` class.

Comment: Or you can declare `List<Report01>` and `List<Report02>` instead of `List<object>` if you actually can.